# How to convert Plain text to Json Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

How to convert plain text into JSON value in Javascript. I tried lot. But unable to fetch as expected. Kindly anybody help

Actual String getting from command line which is executing command from javascript

```
Net State: OFFLINE
Net Err:
Net Time: 0

Current Sample: 0

Sample #0
        Sample Role: OFFLINE
        Sample Status: DISABLED
        Sample Errors: ERROR STATUS
        Test Mode: FAILED
        Test Status: NOT RUNNING      

Sample #1
        Sample Role: ONLINE
        Sample Status: ENABLED
        Sample Errors: NO ERROR
        Test Mode: ENABLED
        Test Status: RUNNING
```

Expected JSON value

```
{
  "Net_State": "OFFLINE",
  "Net_Err": "",
  "Net_Time": 0,
  "Current_sample": 0,
  "Sample": [
        {
      "Sample_Role": "OFFLINE",
      "Sample_Status": "DISABLED",
      "Sample_Errors": "ERROR STATUS",
      "Test_Mode": "FAILED",
      "Test_Status": "NOT RUNNING"
    },
    {
      "Sample_Role": "ONLINE",
      "Sample_Status": "ENABLED",
      "Sample_Errors": "NO ERROR",
      "Test_Mode": "ENABLED",
      "Test_Status": "RUNNING"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried the following code, But how can i write it shortly

```
var res = response.split(/\r?\n/);
res = res.filter(function(e){return e});
var myObject = {
node : []
};
var nodeObject =[];
var i =0, j=0, k = 0, l=0;
var sampleArr = []
var loop = false;
for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
var itemValue = res[i]
if (itemValue.includes(':')) {
        var sp = itemValue.split(':');
        if (!loop) {
        myObject[sp.shift().trim()] = sp.join(':').trim();
    } else {
        if(nodeObject.length > 0) {
            if (j ==0) {
                myObject.node[l] = nodeObject;
                nodeObject = [];
                l = l+1;
            }
        }

        nodeObject.push({[sp.shift().trim()] : sp.join(':').trim()});
        j = j+1;
        if (k > 0 && k == j) {
        myObject.node[l] = nodeObject;
        nodeObject = [];
        }
    }
} else {
    loop = true;
    k=j;        
    j = 0;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's the format of the plain text?

Comment: Its a string which is getting value from command line

Comment: You'll have to manipulate the string you get from the command line yourself. (e.g., add commas and double quotes and braces, etc.)

Comment: `I tried lot. But unable to fetch as expected. ` - What have you tried? Where did it fail? What server-side stack are you using to do this?

Comment: @fubar Updated code in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: You hadn't posted any code when I posted this, so I'm still looking to see where you went wrong to help you understand

OK, the problem your code has (the only problem?) is

```
nodeObject.push({[sp.shift().trim()] : sp.join(':').trim()});
```

Which is why each item in the Sample array is an array of objects

tried to fix that, but the code below is just better anyway (If I do say so myself)

```js
const response = `Net State: OFFLINE
Net Err:
Net Time: 0

Current Sample: 0

Sample #0
        Sample Role: OFFLINE
        Sample Status: DISABLED
        Sample Errors: ERROR STATUS
        Test Mode: FAILED
        Test Status: NOT RUNNING      

Sample #1
        Sample Role: ONLINE
        Sample Status: ENABLED
        Sample Errors: NO ERROR
        Test Mode: ENABLED
        Test Status: RUNNING`;
        
let res = response.split(/\r?\n/g).filter(line => line.trim());
let curr = null;
const result = res.reduce((acc, line) => {
    if (/\s#\d+/.test(line)) { // array entry
        let [key, index] = line.split(' #');
        key = key.trim();
        index = +index;
        curr = {key, index}; // save the key and index
        let a = acc[key] = acc[key] || []; // initialise the array if needed
        a[index] = a[index] || {}; // initialise the object at the given index
    } else {
        let [key, ...value] = line.split(':');
        value = value.join(':').trim();
        if (key.startsWith(' ')) { // array
            acc[curr.key][curr.index][key.trim()] = value;
        } else { // root
            acc[key.trim()] = value;
        }
    }
    return acc;
}, {});
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

Comment: I got an error like Uncaught TypeError: plainText.reduce is not a function

Comment: not if you run it in the above snippet - note, in the above snippet, the plainText variable is an **array**

Comment: Should i convert to array by using split new line?

Comment: that's what the code in the answer does! - as I said, you had posted zero code when I created the above, so ... let me edit it so it fits with your code

Comment: Is that the output you get when you "Run code snippet" in the answer? Don't even know what "Node" property is, it's not in your expected output, and it certainly has **nothing** to do with my answer ... that's something *your* code would probably produce - so, not sure what else you want from me

Comment: Whose? Yours or mine ? :)